# Reflecting polymer/web components interface

Tags: polymer, web-component

i wondered if it is possible in general to retrieve the interface of a polymer-webcomponent. As far as i can see beside attributes there is a lot more to a polymer-webcomponent which is a kind of interface to it, respective events and the light DOM, but i have not grasped yet how this could be determined in a generic and reliable way (read tool-support).

Any hints and comments on this would be much appreciated.
Best Regards,
Hilmar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general area of exploration for web components, not just ones created with Polymer :)

For Polymer, we've created a documentation system (see [core-component-page](https://github.com/polymer/core-component-page) that's loosely based off of JSDocs. It scrapes a component's documented properties, methods, and events and renders a page with basic examples, docs, and a demo link. Example: http://polymer.github.io/core-ajax/components/core-ajax/.

The good news is that properties/methods automatically show up in the devtool console auto-complete  when native custom elements are available in the browser. For things like accepted light dom attributes and css styling hooks,...these will just need solid documentation.

Comment: ok, great - that at least explains the current state to me! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can access a web components interface imperatively by using DOM operations:

```
var fooComponent = document.createElement('foo-component');

fooComponent.doSomething();
```

Where as `fooComponent` could look sth. like this:

```
Polymer('foo-component', {
  doSomething: function () {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Comment: ok, thanks. This might be ok to get heuristically some information, though your example is more about to instantiate an element imperatively than to get real metadata about attributes and events. but e.g. the whole light DOM is not explicitly described in the component but only implicitly handled in shadow DOM (<content select=""></content), for me this is right now a gap in the concept as i would think that a component should expose explicit metadata so that someone can actually build a solid designtime for webcomponents. Or am i missing still something?